# Cann't get http response when exception happens on server side in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to request http post to server. It works fine if everything is ok. But I can't get the response when the server throw an exception. In browser, I should be able to get the 505 error code. But I can't get it in swift. Below is the code I used. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
             //this method is not called
            print("get response from register service \(data) \(error)")

        })

        task.resume()
```

Comment: It sounds strange. You might try curl - or even a better tool like Wireshark - in order to confirm that the server response is correct.

Comment: I did try with browser and postman,  I could get the error response immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (let data, response, let error) in
        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
            // no response code
            return
        }
        completeHandler(data, response, error)
    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: I have tried but it is still not working. The problem is that when server throw an exception, the completionHandler is not called.

Comment: Did you mean that `// no response code` does not reach at all ?

Comment: No, whenever the backend server throw an exception, the swift code is not called until timed out. When I use browser to access the same url, I can get the 505 internal error immediately.